# Store table data in a sql database

Tags: sql

I'm building an application where the user can build custom schedules. I'm currently thinking about how to store the user created schedule.

Since the users will be able to create custom columns a generic table for all data won't work. My current approach would be to create a new database table for every table a user creates. However I don't know if that would be considered best practice.

Comment: You could use one table and include a JSON column to mock the custom columns created by the users

Comment: You might want to consider using temp or temporal tables. You woudnt want to create a table every time and stretch database size unless you have unlimited resources which can handle as DB size grows bigger